# Want to create one list with one Id and multiple ProviderId values like

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to create one list with one Id and multiple ProviderId values like

```
Id ProviderId
1  "val1" 
1  "val2"
```

I have a model class as per below :

```
public class Model
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public List<PrefDictionary> ProviderId { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have created one list as per below :

```
List<PrefDictionary> PrefData = data.Select(p => new PrefDictionary()
                                    {
                                        _1 = p.PrefDictionary._1,
                                        _2 = p.PrefDictionary._2
                                    }).ToList();
```

Here in data I am getting whole json format data and one node is like this below for PrefDictionary.

```
data = {
Id : 1,
PrefDictionary{
1: "Val1",
2: "Val2"
}}
```

Now then I have created one more list as per below :

```
List<Model> PP = data.Select(p => new Model()
                                    {
                                        Id = p.Id,
                                        ProviderId = PrefData.Select(x => new PrefDictionary()
                                        {
                                            _1 = x._1,
                                            _2 = x._2
                                        }).ToList(),
                                    }).ToList();
}
```

But the problem is I am getting empty in second column list in first I am getting Id but not getting any value in second column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% I understand JSON format you are expecting. However, if you want a list of providers - each with a list of preferences - then I think you'll need another class to get this to serialize properly:

```
public class Model
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public List<Providers> providers { get; set; }
    }


public class Providers
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public List<PrefDictionary> ProviderId { get; set; }
    }
```

This should give you the JSON output:

```
{
  "Providers": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "PrefDictionary": [
        {
          "Val1": "",
          "Val2": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "PrefDictionary": [
        {
          "Val1": "",
          "Val2": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem could be the way how you deserialize your data object.

Based on your code, I've created the result that contains the PrefDirectonary.
[image].

However, one thing I did for the data variable was to make an object like this,

```
PrefDictionary pd = new PrefDictionary 
{
  _1 = "Value1",
  _2 = "Value2"
};

List<TestObject> data = new List<TestObject>() {
 new TestObject
 {
    Id = "1",
    PrefDictionary = pd
 }
};
```

It will be helpful to show us how you deserialize the JSON data object.